# Error in trigger for notifications. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I create a local notification, which should come every day at 9 am.
I used to do this, and it worked. Now for some reason it gives the following error ...

Please tell me how to solve this correctly!

```
     let date = Date()
    var triggerDate = 
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second,], from: 
date)
    triggerDate.hour = 9
      triggerDate.minute = 0
      triggerDate.second = 0

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Oneindifer", 
content: content, trigger: triggerDate) /*ERROR - Cannot convert 
value of type 'DateComponents' to expected argument type 
'UNNotificationTrigger?'*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is pass a `UNNotificationTrigger` in the `trigger` parameter. You are currently passing `DateComponents`. Try replacing your code with this:

```swift
let date = Date()
var triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
triggerDate.hour = 9
triggerDate.minute = 0
triggerDate.second = 0

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

**Alternatively:**
Take a look at this answer for a `UIViewController` extension. It is a function that lets you easily create a `UNNotificationRequest`: [Send a local notification when timer is up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58332313/send-a-local-notification-when-timer-is-up/58333038#58333038)

In your case, you could use the extension in the answer linked above like so: `self.createLocalNotification(title: "9 hours have passed", hours: 9)`

Comment: Awesome! Good luck sir

Answer (score 0):

It's work!

```
 let date = Date()
    var triggerDate = 
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second,], from: 
date)
    triggerDate.hour = 9
      triggerDate.minute = 0
      triggerDate.second = 0

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Oneindifer", 
content: content, trigger: trigger)
```